# data binding to drop down box in Spring MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have simple spring mvc web application.I want to bind list into drop down.In this case list items are normally bind into drop down; but If I select item and click submit button it is always passing "0" instead of value.

### This is my controller.

```
public EditEmployeeController() {
        setCommandClass(Employee.class);
        setCommandName("employee");
}

@Override
protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    Map referenceData = new HashMap();        
    List roleList = roleService.listRoles();
    referenceData.put("roleList", roleList);
    return referenceData;
}

@Override
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        Object command,
        BindException errors) throws Exception {
    Employee employee = (Employee) command;
    employeeService.updateEmployee(employee);
    return new ModelAndView(getSuccessView());
}
```

This is my view(jsp)

```
<c:nestedPath path="employee">
            <form method="post" action="./EditEmployee.htm">
........
.......

Select Role :                
<c:bind path="roleID">
 <select name="roleLists">
   <s:forEach items="${roleList}" var="role" >
       <option value="<s:out value="${role.roleID}"/>" <s:if test="${role.roleID == status.value}"> selected="selected"</s:if>><s:out value="${role.title}"/></option>
        </s:forEach>
  </select>
</c:bind>
<input type="submit" value="Update employee"/
</form>
</c:nestedPath>
```

Any idea for solve my problem..??

Thank in advance!

Comment: Off topic - your JSTL tablib prefixes are a bit non-standard; it's not a big deal but I had to look twice at your code. Most people use c for the JSTL core library, and spring (or s, no biggie) for the Spring library :) You have c for Spring and s for Core - not a problem, just odd! Anyway, my advice is to check the HTML of your rendered page and make sure that your select box has the IDs populated. It'd also be useful if you could post your Employee class - just in case.

Comment: I also recommend you check out the Spring Form tag library to simplify data binding: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib

Answer (score 3):

Use Spring form tag

add `<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>` in your jsp

and use the code below

```
<form:select path="role"  id="role" >
    <form:options items="${roleList}" itemValue="roleID" itemLabel="title"/>
</form:select>
```